# React setState error - can not update after first time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, fetch-api

I want to handle two **errors** with one React state.

The first is when the user has not yet put in / (typed) a search term e.g **pitbull**  the state is set to **Please type in a breed**

The second is when the user types in a search term, a wrong input (a breed of dog that does not exist) e.g **Foot Bar** Once the state is set to **Breed not found** it fails to revert back to **Please type in a breed** If the input field is cleared.

[Here is a link to the working web app](https://ifeanyi-typescript-dogs.netlify.app/)

```js
// get the images of the breed that is choosen
  const loadByBreed = async (value: string) => {
    
    
    if (!nameOfBreeds.includes(value)) {
      setFetchError("Breed not found")
    };
    
    if(!value && value === "") {
      setFetchError("Please type in a breed name");
      return;
    }


    try {


      const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${value}/images`)
      const data = await response.json()   
      
    

      // if (data.message === "Breed not found (master breed does not exist)"  ) {
        
      //   setFetchError(data.message.slice(0, 16));
      // }

      console.log(data.message)
      setImagesOfABreed(data.message)
      
      
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as Error
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => { 
  
    loadByBreed(debouncedQuery);
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [debouncedQuery])
```

Comment: when you remove the input text, thats is the exact value of value?

Comment: please come again, I do not understand your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

oh my God. I am super elated right now.

**Here is the solution**

```js
const handleSearchChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (!e.target.value) return;

    setSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };
```

This is basically returning, when the target-value is empty

Means when you empty the search, it never is set to empty again

Means, it always has at least one letter in it

Means it always shows **"breed not found"**